# Intercept traffic in open wifi hotspot to scare family into using VPN

Tags: security, vpn, wireless-access-point, internet-security

I recently setup my own VPN and I love it. Now I'm staying at a hotel and there is only a public wifi hotspot that doesn't even require a password. I'm using my VPN, but my family won't listen to me to do it. I want to scare them by showing them I (or a malicious wifi hotspot) can literally read their internet traffic. Any ideas how I can do this?
I've see recommendations online for using Wireshark but it seems you need a separate piece of hardware to use it in Promiscuous mode, which I don't have. Any other ideas?

Comment: Promiscuous mode is a mode, not a specific piece of hardware. Your wireless card may or may not support this mode.

Comment: you want to show them that you can read their traffic, except that you can't?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't even need to mess with promiscuous mode.  Just launch wireshark on your own PC, wireshark will automatically capture the packets from your PC.  Ask your family member to log into their e-mail (on your PC).  After they have done this, ask them to logout.  Search your capture and find their password (which travels in clear text across an open wifi) - Present them with their password - Badabing!

Comment: Thanks! But just tried it (logged into ESPN), and it looks like it used TLS 1.2 protocol, so I can't read it because it's encrypted. So doesn't look like that will work.

Comment: I thought you mentioned that the Wi-Fi is un-encrypted... Anyway, if you're using EAP-TLS then you've got nothing to worry about.  You could setup an open/un-encrypted SSID on your home router and try the test I described above.

Comment: @pythonian, I think he means when he connected to ESPN the website was using https/tls for the handshake. In this case, the password would not be sent in clear text.